# How to retrieve fellow students from many-to-many relationship with Linq

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I am using EF6 code first and MVC 5. I have two model classes which have many-to-many relationship with each other. EF has also generated a junction table for me which contains foreign keys to both Student And Course table.

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } 
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } 
}
```

For "Student A" I want to list his fellow students who are registered in the same course or courses as "Student A". If a student is registered in "Course A" and "Course B", in my Action method how can I get a list of students who are registered in "Course A" and "Course B" from the StudentId ?

I have searched alot but couldn't find any specific answers. Any help will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain SQL this could be done by cross joining the junction table with itself and then filtering the result rows:

```
select distinct sc2.[StudentId]
from StudentsCourses sc1
cross join StudentsCourses sc2
where sc1.[StudentId] = 12345 and sc1.[CourseId] = sc2.[CourseId]
```

Entity Framework doesn't give access to the StudentsCourses table, but you can try to emulate such cross join by using the following C# code:

```
from sc1 in (db.Students.SelectMany(s1 => s1.Courses.Select(c1 => new { Student = s1, Course = c1 })))
from sc2 in (db.Students.SelectMany(s2 => s2.Courses.Select(c2 => new { Student = s2, Course = c2 })))
where sc1.Student.StudentId == 12345 && sc1.Course.CourseId == sc2.Course.CourseId
select sc2.Student;
```

But I'm not sure whether EF will generate SQL efficiently, so you should check it by using SQL profiler. Probably, it would be better to use the `ExecuteQuery` method with a string .

Comment: Thanks alot Vorrtex that worked for me. I will check it with the profiler and see how does it go. Once again thanks :)